# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre x:Key y x:Name?

Tags: wpf, xaml

En WPF, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre `x:Key` y `x:Name`? ¿En qué casos hay que usar una o la otra?

Sé que `x:Key` puede ser seteado con una `markup-extension` así:

```
x:Key="{x:Static local:MisKeys.MiKey}"
```

Pero `x:Name` no. ¿Por qué es esto? No me gusta *hardcodear* `strings` y con `x:Name` me veo forzada a hacerlo.

Quisiera saber si ambas propiedades son "intercambiables" en algún contexto, porque prefiero usar `x:Key` todo lo posible ya que la puedo *setear* con una constante.

Comment: @pzin he colocado y actualizado mi respuesta abajo para que la revises.

Comment: Preguntó @Dzyann, no yo. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.Key` es una propiedad de un ítem dentro de un `ResourceDictionary`. Es usado para identificar un recurso dentro de un diccionario de recursos.

En cambio `x:Name` es el *identificador* en C# que corresponde a la etiqueta XAML a la cual se le agrega el `x:Name`, de esta manera es como lo puedes referenciar desde *C#*.

Con este ejemplo espero que todo quede claro:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="NameDelGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KeyDelBrush" Color="White"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Grid grid = NameDelGrid; // NameDelGrid es un identificador C#
        SolidColorBrush resource = (SolidColorBrush)grid.Resources["KeyDelBrush"]; // KeyDelBrush es un string que identifica al resource dentro del ResourceDictionary
        string color = resource.Color.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(color);
    }
```

En este ejemplo se muestra en un MessageBox el valor `#FFFFFFFF` que corresponde al color blanco.

Como puedes observar `NameDelGrid` es el nombre de un campo que le pertenece a `MainWindow`, no es un valor que pueda ser modificado dinámicamente sino que es el nombre de una propiedad de la clase.

Comment: Yo no quiero modificarlo dinamicamente, mas bien solo quiero asignarle una constante. Porque cuando haces CustomControls necesitas buscar los items por el nombre, y no te queda otra que escribir el nombre del elemento otra vez. Igual entiendo tu punto y el que menciono arriba JuanK.

Answer (score 2):

`x:Key` se usa para identificar objetos en un diccionario de recursos:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ElEstilo" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ElEstilo}" />
</Grid>
```

`x:Name` se usa para identificar elementos de interfaz de usuario:

```
<TextBox x:Key="ElTextBox" />
```

Puedes añadir un `x:Name` a un recurso, pero no puedes usar su valor para referenciarlo con `StaticResource`. No puedes usar `x:Key` fuera de un diccionario de recursos.

Comment: Osea que no son intercambiables en ningun contexto? Y no hay forma de no tener que hardcodear el valor de `x:Name`?

Comment: no está hardcodeado, básicamente le estás poniendo nombre a una variable.

Comment: @JuanK - No me notifico tu respuesta. Si esta hardcodeado, porque si necesito referenciarla desde otro lado, no puedo a menos que escriba de nuevo el mismo string, lo que puede derivar en errores.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno llevo un tiempo frio con **XAML** (pero solia ser muy bueno modestia a aparte)

Basta con poner el `Name` y marcar el acceso al texbox como `public` para que lo puedas acceder como un miembro de la instancia desde fuera de la misma.

El uso del `Name` incluso si tienes que escribirlo siempre como `string` siempre será la alternativa a seguir para acceder al árbol de objetos de UI dentro de XAML.

### No estás hardcodeando nada

La plataforma se diseñó así. Para acceder a un objeto dentro del 'DOM' xaml debes navegar a través de una compleja jerarquía de objetos y cuando la UI es bastante rica se vuelve un tema de a**divinar en qué objeto de la jerarquía estas**.

Para evitar ello entonces puedes identificar a los objetos por su nombre, si tienes todo muy bien montado con MVVM raras veces necesitarás ello porque el binding se encargará de resolver lo necesario, sin embargo siempre encontrarás escenario donde el binding por sí solo no es suficiente para resolverlo todo (a veces es que no eres tan bueno con MVVM como crees, pero eso es otro tema). En esos casos debes buscar la forma más adecuada de interactuar con algún/os objetos de la jerarquía, y la forma más sencilla es por el nombre.

Cuando el objeto tiene nombre puedes accederlo directamente desde **code behind** y si requieres acceder a este por fuera de la clase donde está definido entonces lo marcas como `public`.

### Porqué el `Name`

Un objeto definido dentro de XAML no es más que un field/property dentro de una clase, solo que no lo defines con código de programación sino con etiquetas. Si quieres usar ese field/property entonces deberás ponerle nombre.

Ponerle Name a un objeto también es util para algunos escenarios de binding donde el binding de un objeto esta relacionado con el de otro.

### Binding

Por ejemplo tienes un `Slider` y deseas que el valor del slider modifique la opacidad de un objeto `Image` en ese caso tienes que hacer que la propiedad `Opacity` del `Image` haga binding con la propiedad `Value` del `Slider`... y no hay forma de hacerlo decentemente sino asignándole `Name` al `Slider`.

### Creatividad

> Yo no quiero modificarlo dinámicamente, mas bien solo quiero asignarle
>   una constante. Porque cuando haces CustomControls necesitas buscar los
>   items por el nombre, y no te queda otra que escribir el nombre del
>   elemento otra vez.

Recuerda que un XAML es solo la mitad de una clase parcial, la otra mitad es desde luego el code behind.

Si quieres tener una forma de acceder rápidamente a un objeto de tu UI, podrías entonces nombrarlo y exponerlo como `public`, es decir una propiedad dentro de tu clase, tambien en en el codebehind puedes encapsular la forma en que accedes a sus  propiedades y exponer solo lo que deseas como propiedades públicas.

A veces he tenido que permitir que un obejeto específico sea accedido globalmente, en ese caso lo que hago es manejar una clase estática en toda la app donde referenciar algunos objetos cuyo acceso es importante y me encargo de asignar dichos campos estáticos con la instancia correspondiente desde el codebehind de un XAML, ejemplo

```
public void Loaded(...)
{
   StaticResourceSharer.TheTextBlock = this.MiTextBlock;
}
```

Parece sencillo pero no lo es, en medio pueden haber verdaderas pesadillas, pero para casos básicos siempre puede ser una salida para cambiar alguna propiedad específica de la UI etc... eso sí *siempre que llegues a este escenario* debes tener claro que **tu estrategia de binding está incompleta** y no estas manejando el estado de algunas cosas que **deberían hacer parte del modelo** (ViewModel).

### Y los Key

Los `key`, como bien te lo han dicho son descriptores de un objeto en un grupo de recursos, si piensas en el grupo de recursos este no es más que una colección  de objetos que quiero utilizar en determinado escenario. No es casualidad que que se llamen Diccionarios, porque a la final eso son, diccionarios muy parecidos a un `Dictionary<string, object` una colección donde puedes acceder a sus objetos utilizando una llave que hace las veces de índice.

Defines el key cuando tienes un objeto que deseas accederlo como recurso, por ejemplo:

- Un estilo  gráfico definido para tus textblocks
- Un datasource que deseas usarlo luego como datacontext / viewmodel en uno o varios objetos

Comment: Gracias Juan por tu respuesta. Ya se que la plataforma esta hecha asi, eso no quiere decir que este bien. El hecho de que el Name tenga que ser un string, con la forma en que funcionan los Custom Controls hace que tengas que escribir dos veces el mismo texto (el nombre del control) como minimo, lo cual me molesta porque puede causar errores a futuro, y ademas sin querer puedes cambiar el nombre en un lado y al compilar no va a fallar. Por eso es que preguntaba si alguien sabia de alguna forma en que se pueda poner el Name en un solo lugar.

Comment: Pero no te entiendo. Name es un string solo en el XAML, para la clase es un field comun y corriente, no veo donde debes definirlo 2 veces. Para el programa es un field que puedes acceder desde donde quieras de acuerdo a las restricciones de acceso que tu mismo expongas. Incluso VS te puede hacer intellisense de el tanto a nivel de Code Behind como a nivel de XAML. Creo que te estas ahogando en un vaso con agua, es decir opino que estas dando vueltas con un problema que no existe.

Comment: JuanK, hm, pienso que quizas no has trabajado con CustomControls? No es un UserControl del que hablo. Un CustomControl no tiene Code-behind y xaml asociados, mas bien estan disociados. Al control se le aplica un ControlTemplate que hayas definido, se usa para theming y extensibilidad. [Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278064%28VS.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) puedes ver como el Name esta en el xaml, y despues en el codigo del control tenes que hacer GetTemplatedChild("NombreDelControl"), para poder acceder al control.

Comment: @Dzyann Si , lo he hecho, pero ahi voy. Necesitas llamar a un objeto que pertenece a un 'DOM'  usualmente complejo. Necesitas acceder a esa instancia en particular entonces solo tienes dos formas de hacerlo: acceder a ella directamente: fácil si ya tienes una referencia a ella en tiempo de compilación, o buscarla cuando es creada dinámicamente que es el caso en que debes usar GetTemplatedChild.

Comment: Sino fuera por un string o identificador de qué otra forma podrías buscarla? ninguna, necesitarías una referencia directa al campo pero precisamente no la tienes porque el objeto es creado dinámicamente al aplicar el template a una instancia en tiempo de ejecución. sin embargo entiendo tu sentir porque ya pasé por ahí. Le di muchas vueltas al asunto y realmente es la única solución posible, bien sea buscando por un string o buscando por cualquier otro id disponible. La instancia no existe en tiempo de compilación, hay que hacer una búsqueda dinámica.

Comment: si de algo sirve, para evitar la manipulación excesiva de los string puedes crear un objeto intermedio con variables / constantes de solo lectura donde cargues desde el inicio los nombres de los objetos del template. No es perfecto pero si una mejora.